# WordPress/MySQL - Apostrophes being output as question marks

Tags: wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding, apostrophe, latin1

I'm moving a client's WordPress site from an old host to a shiny new one. I've done a MySQL Dump of the WP database, and imported it into the new host.

Everything has worked smoothly, except, **apostrophes are being encoded as question marks**.

I've done a little research and the closest I've got is saving the .sql dump in UTF8 (which I've done), then trying to import again - no luck. I've also changed every reference of `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;` in the MySQL dump to `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`, however, this also makes no difference.

In some odd cases (I can't remember the exact configuration), apostrophes are lost entirely, not replaced with anything, but they just disappear.

They aren't standard straight apostrophes (`&#39;`) but rather right curly quotes I believe (`&#146;`) - e.g. they're ’, not '. Hope that comes out ok on SO!

Any advice?

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: Have you reviewed the information on the codex in relation to database character sets, namingly this one.. http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets

Comment: Thank you t31os, I followed the instructions there and the problem is solved. Cheers!

Comment: Happy to hear you got the problem resolved.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do they appear as `?`? When you view it in your browser?

Do you send UTF8 as charset in the headers?

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: In both the browser, and in the database rows. I'll look into the charset header now.